# Extract address lines from comma seperated text using reg ex

Tags: .net, regex

I need regular expressions (dot net) to extract address lines from comma separated text.

**1. Need exactly address2 from the input**

input: *address1, **address2**, address3*

output: *address2*

I have tried `Regex.Match(strInput, @"^(?:[^,]*\,){1}([^,]*)").Value` but it gives address1,address2

**2. Need address2 and anything after address2**

input: *address1, **address2, address3***

output: *address2, address3*

I have tried `Regex.Match(strInput, @"^(?:[^,]*\,){1}(.*)").Value` but it gives full input text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather just split the string with coma in this case you're describing.

But if you just prefer regular expression, all you need to do is to get the **first matched subsequence** instead of the whole match. (i.e. replace `.Value` with `.Groups[1].Value`)

The code would be

**1.** `Regex.Match(strInput, @"^(?:[^,]*\,){1}([^,]*)").Groups[1].Value`

**2.** `Regex.Match(strInput, @"^(?:[^,]*\,){1}(.*)").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Splitting the text will solve my first requirement, but difficult for the second. It may need another step for concat. So regex is preferred in this case. Any idea with better performance is welcome.